# A simple app to add tags to questions given a search criterium

Tags: app, api-v2.2, tags

In the wake of the *-vba situation on Stack Overflow, one tag remains, that should be retagged to two others. See [this MSO post for more details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399177).

To resolve this situation, this is a mini-app, that does the following:

It fetches questions tagged access-vba that are not tagged ms-access

It adds the ms-access tag to these questions (reporting any questions with 5 tags, though these should have been removed manually up front).

Afterwards, the access-vba tag can be merged with the vba tag.

Because I only do weird programming languages, this app has been entirely written in R.
It's closed-source and single-user (can be open-sourced if there's a desire but credentials are hard-coded for now, and workflow is poor with manual copy-pasting of the access token).

This means further documentation is absent.